# HTTPClient error An invalid request URI was provided

Tags: c#, http, httpclient

I am trying to get the content from a web page using this code :

```
HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
var response = await http.GetByteArrayAsync("www.nsfund.ir/news?p_p_id=56_INSTANCE_tVzMoLp4zfGh&_56_INSTANCE_tVzMoLp4zfGh_mode=news&_56_INSTANCE_tVzMoLp4zfGh_newsId=3135919&p_p_state=maximized");
String source = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetString(response, 0, response.Length - 1);
source = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(source);
HtmlDocument resultat = new HtmlDocument();
resultat.LoadHtml(source);
```

But I get this error :

> An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.

Comment: try `http://www.......`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You simply need to specify the full URL ( including the protocol) like this:

```
var response = await http.GetByteArrayAsync("http://www.nsfund.ir/news?p_....
```

Answer (score 15):

An absolute URI follows the `protocol://server/path?query#hash` convention. As you did not specify a protocol, specifically `http://` or `https://` in your case, the URL is not absolute and thus cannot be resolved.

Comment: You saved my day, I have been trying to make it work for the last hour, turned out I had a single slash (`http:/`)...